# Create a file as executable program in C in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu

My program receives an executable binary file through a TCP socket.

I need to save this file in to the harddisk as a executable program. File is successfully received but the problem is the default file attribute is being set to non executable.

How to change the file's attribute as executable in C in Ubuntu?

Thank you,
Regards,
Robo

Comment: The answers are right, but this is probably not a very good idea...

Comment: By what mechanism are you sure that the received executable is never a malicious one?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - I am programming for a cluster Machines. Sender will also be a one part of the whole application which runs on master node. So there is no any malicious issues.

Comment: @R.. - So what would be a good idea for this problem?

Comment: Well the code should be transferred securely, so that a compromised machine on the network couldn't inject malicious code. Transferring it over ssh, or over https with certificate checking, or just using cryptographic hashes/signatures over a secure channel and sending the binary over an otherwise-insecure channel, would all work ok

Comment: Yes... You are correct. I am now considering using MPI for this. I think It will manage every security issues. Still exploring MPI... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about `int chmod(const char *path, mode_t mode)` and `int fchmod(int fd, mode_t mode) ?`

```
apropos chmod
man 2 chmod
```

The most basic example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

   char * fpath = "/path/to/binary";
   int ret=0;
   if(ret = chmod(fpath, S_IRUSR|S_IXUSR) < 0){
      perror("chmod failed");
      exit(1);
   }

   printf("chmod ok\n");
   exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you creating and writing the file?  If you *know* it's going to be executable, just make the file with the correct mode in the first place.

```
int fd = open("path/to/file", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, 0777);
```

Unless `umask` is stripping the executable bits (common values are `0022` and `0002` which leave the executable bits alone), `path/to/file` will be created initially executable.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the file mode with `chmod`. Read the man page(`man 2 chmod`) for detail(roughly the same as shell command `chmod`).